# invalid input syntax for integer with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a table:

```
                id | detail
                 1 | ddsffdfdf ;df, deef,"dgfgf",/dfdf/
```

when I did: `insert into details values(1,'ddsffdfdf ;df, deef');` => got inserted properly
When I copied that inserted value from database to a file,the file had: `1 ddsffdfdf ;df, deef`
Then I loaded the whole csv file to pgsql database,with values in the format: `1 ddsffdfdf ;df, deef`
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "1 ddsffdfdf ;df, deef is obtained. How to solve the  problem?

Comment: How are you loading the CSV file in PG ?

Comment: copy details from '/usr/local/bin/details.csv' ;

Comment: Please edit your question and include the **exact** statement you used to import the file and the **exact** content of the _file_.

Answer (score 3):

CSVs need a delimiter that Postgres will recognize to break the text into respective fields.  Your delimiter is a space, which is insufficient.  Your CSV file should look more like:

```
1,"ddsffdfdf df, deef"
```

And your SQL should look like:

```
COPY details FROM 'filename' WITH CSV;
```

The *WITH CSV* is important because it tells Postgres to use a comma as the delimiter and parses your values based on that.  Because your second field contains a comma, you want to enclose its value in quotes so that its comma is not mistaken for a delimiter.

To look at a good example of a properly formatted CSV file, you can output your current table:

```
COPY details TO '/your/filename.csv' WITH CSV;
```

Comment: I have tried with  delimiter ,  but it is also error

Comment: you misunderstood: do NOT have space as delimiter

Comment: @user3823859 if you use a comma delimiter, you need to use appropriate quotes around other values that contain commas.

Comment: You included *WITH CSV*?  What error are you getting?  Does your CSV contain the field names, or no?

Comment: ERROR:  extra data after last expected column

Comment: Did you put quotes around it?

Comment: yes, now the file contains 1,"ddsffdfdf ;df, deef,"dgfgf",/dfdf/"

Comment: Run `COPY details TO '/your/filename.csv' WITH CSV;` from your database and look at how the CSV should look.  You'll have to escape inner-quotes

Comment: It is of the form 1,"ddsffdfdf ;df, deef,"dgfgf",/dfdf/"

Comment: I think if your CSV value has quotes you can use double quotes to escape them: `1,"ddsffdfdf ;df, deef,""dgfgf"",/dfdf/"`

Comment: is  it possible to remove the double quotes while fetching back?

Comment: The `WITH CSV` option will handle that, but you can try it and let us know.

Comment: That way also,it is throwing erro. ERROR:  extra data after last expected column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79131/discussion-between-vol7ron-and-user3823859).